# Find Gain K and Time constant K of a system from the time response

Tags: control-theory, optimal-control, linear-control, discrete-time, steady-state

There is a given system $\frac{K}{sT + 1}$ of order 1. The responses are in the image below and the 2 inputs are $u1(t) = 1(t)$ and $u_2(t) = \sqrt{2} \cdot \sin(\omega_2 t)$. How can I find the K and T of the system.

[image]

As far I know I have calculated the frequency by dividing the cycles by time and then using the w = 2pif to get the frequency of system. Gain would be 2 as for unit step the final value is 2. I am looking for an alternative easy solution which can be applied from frequency response such as calculating the w and T from gain k = 2, input signal and transfer function.

Comment: Did you achieve any progress on that yourself?

Comment: I know the solution by traditional methods such as looking the freq and getting the wavelength. I am looking for an alternative easy solution which can be applied from frequency response such as calculating the gain (K = 2) from the u1(t) and y1ss(t), how to find w and T.

Comment: Then, please share what you have done so far.

Comment: Please read [how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question). It’s better to show your attempt in the post. You can also add relevant definitions, possible strategies, some particular examples, where is this problem from, why is it interesting and important, and other [context](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/9960#9960). Not in the comment, but in the **post** itself, since it’s crucial information.

Comment: @KBS I have made some edits Kindy check.

Answer (score 0):

The transfer function $H(s)$ is:

$$H(s)=\frac{K}{sT+1} \qquad (1)$$

If the system input is $U(s)$, then the output $Y(s)$ is:

$$Y(s) = U(s)H(s) $$

The response to the input $u_1(t)= u_{-1}(t)$, where $u_{-1}(t)$ represents the step function, is:

$$Y(s) = \frac{1}{s}\frac{K}{sT+1} \qquad (2)$$

The Final Value Theorem is:

$$ \lim_{t \to \infty} y(t)= y(\infty)=\lim_{s \to 0}sY(s) $$

Through first graph $y(\infty)=2$. Then, applying the above theorem to $(2)$:

$$K=2$$

Considering the frequency response ($s= j\omega$), expression $(1)$ becomes:

$$H(\omega)=\frac{2}{j \omega T+1}$$

With corresponding magnitude:

$$ \left | H(\omega) \right |= \frac{2}{\sqrt{1+(\omega T)^2}} \qquad (3)$$

As the frequency of the output for a sinusoidal input is not changed for a linear time invariant system and, if $u_2(t)=\sqrt{2}\sin(\omega_2 t)$, then through the second graph is possible to get:

$$\omega_2=\frac{2\pi}{5}=0.4\pi \space \mathrm{rad/s}$$

Thus:

$$u_2(t)=\sqrt{2}\sin(0.4\pi t)$$

Still considering the second graph, for a sinusoidal input with amplitude $\sqrt{2}$ and frequency $\omega=\omega_2=0.4\pi \space \mathrm{rad/s}$, the magnitude of the output will be $2$. Therefore:

$$\left | Y(0.4\pi) \right |= \left | U(0.4\pi) \right | \left | H(0.4\pi) \right |=\sqrt{2} \space \frac{2}{\sqrt{1+(0.4\pi T)^2}}=2$$

Resolving for $T$ (in seconds):

$$T=\frac{2.5}{\pi}$$

Comment: @KBS I'm a new contributor here, but I think you're assuming two facts: [1] That it's an exercise (in which case you could have asked for the question to be closed) and [2] That the solution is obvious to all readers. Also, would you have been happier if I had answered half the question (e.g. just about K)?

Comment: What is the reason for the downvote?

Comment: It is easy to spot questions coming from a howework. There are usually specifically crafted to be answered using very specific tools taught at an undergraduate level, and use very clean data. This question checks all those marks. This place is not to solve exercises for others, rather help solve them. The usual way is to ask for posters to put their effort and guide them towards a solution. Giving the solution does not make posters in any favors. Note, finally, such questions are not forbidden as per the website guidelines and cannot be closed because of that.

Comment: I don't agree. At least on other SE sites, it takes three votes to close a suspected homework question. Also the OP could be self-studying from an academic book, not necessarily being student. You didn't answer my question in my last comment, too. Yes, I have seen complete solutions here. As you and possibly others did not agree with the way my solution was given (not technically, but just out of foolishness), including giving negative votes without explanation, I do not intend to be part of this group of resentful and relationship-difficult people . I'm better off here.

Comment: Homework questions have been discussed in the meta and the emerging consensus was that they were not against the guidelines per se. However, it was asked that OP shou;ld show some effort in trying to solve the problem before helping. Whether you agree or not is irrelevant here, this is what had been discussed.